# How to retrieve Steamwork SDK's current version

Tags: c++, steam, steamworks-api

Is it possible to get steamworks SDK's current version through C++ from the Steamworks API?

If yes, how?

[This is what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CHoC.png)

Comment: Are you referring to the `STEAMAPPLIST_INTERFACE_VERSION` variable at this doc: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamClient?

Comment: @darclander that looks likes what I need yes. Thank you. :)

Comment: great! I read a bit more about it and it seems to be the version of either the apps interface or the applists interface. Is that still related to your question? If so, should we write an answer for future people who might have the same question?

Comment: Looking at it, it's not what I needed after all. :( I updated my question with what I'm looking for more precisely

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ISteamAppList * GetISteamAppList( HSteamUser hSteamUser, HSteamPipe hSteamPipe, const char *pchVersion );
...

pchVersion  const char *    The version string that identifies the version of the interface that you receive.
Retrieves the ISteamAppList interface associated with the specified user handle, only available on specially registered apps.
```